# iOS only 3D engine/SDK for C++

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, ipad, 3d

I'm researching which engine/sdk I should use for 3D iOS development in C++
Although there have been questions like this, I haven't found the best solution for my requirements so I'm looking forward to hear your experiences.

- Unity and UDK are not what I'm looking for, due to lack of control.
- Shiva3D looks interesting but don't need the extra editor
- ninevehgl no skinned models and no C++
- Marmalade perfect but multi-platform not required

requirements:

- licensed or open source, preferably licensed which means a more extended sdk/engine
- iOS iPhone/iPad, multi platform with android not preferred.
- fast loading of both rigid and skinned/rigged 3d models
- C++

My current choice would be Marmalade which I have been testing for a while now but I've had some issues where results differ from device to device so that's why i prefer an iOS only option. And most games I see using Marmalade are just using it to port an existing iOS app to android and not publishing to iOS.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/?q=iOS%203D%20Engine%20C%2B%2B) is a good place to start.

Comment: I was asking for user experiences with the engines and sdks that I've listed in this question which have been thoroughly researched using google and practically tested on several machines and devices, I was hoping for a more professional comment than this Mr. Richard

Comment: Then this question may be better suited to [gamedev.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try PowerVR Insider SDK.

- It contains an app framework
- It's in C++
- It contains  modules to load 3d models
- Nice math lib with vector and matrix support

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-insider.asp

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great sdk

Answer (score 0):

Also consider cocos3d library. It is free and robust for iPad/iPhone and utilizes OpenGLES 1.1/2.0. You can load models from Wavefront OBJ format or directly into the interface.

Comment: Thanks but it's Objective-C which I don't like at all.